# Link ASP template login/registration with separate MySql database server?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio

I am relatively proficient with C# in general, but I am a total ASP novice. So this question may seem amateur-ish.

I have created a website from Visual Studio's default ASP.NET website template, which includes login/registration pages (Login.aspx/Login.aspx.cs and Register.aspx/Register.aspx.cs, respectively). Additionally, the IdentityModel.cs file provides code for signing in users and managing sessions.

However, I don't want my application to access a local database file - I want it to access a separate database server (at least while I am testing). I have tried changing the connection string in Web.config to point to the IP of my database server, but I was unsure of how to format the string correctly (the standard "server=[server];uid=[username];pw=[password];" approach didn't work).

**What I am trying to do is use my database server as the data source for the ASP template's default login/registration code. Under this model, when a user attempts to log in, the default C# authorization code retrieves data from this separate SQL server, which is configured through Plesk and administrated through phpMyAdmin. In other words, I want to use the ASP template's default login/registration/authorization code to connect to a separate MySql database server. This way, I will not have to rewrite all of the login/registration/session management code.**

I don't see a necessity to provide any code examples - all I want to know is how I can configure my application to access a separate MySql database server *and still use the default ASP login/registration/session management code.* But if I am wrong, and more details are required, I will happily oblige.

My Web.config file looks something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
       connectionString="server=[ip-address];uid=[user-name];pwd=[password];database=[database-name];"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<\connectionStrings>
```

It initially looked like this:

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection"
           <connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet-[project-name-hash];AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-[project-name-hash].mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 <\connectionStrings>
```

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest showing your Web.Config file for starters so we can see your connection string without you showing us your password, you are aware you can add multiple Connection string key value pairs that point to 2 or more different databases. also why are you using ASP get up to speed on using aspx files. there is a site called [Connections Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: I *am* using ASPX files. I'm using "ASP" in referring to the framework itself. And sounds good - the Web.config file is still in the default state, so I'll edit and add the config info.

Comment: when I see `ASP` I think `Classic-ASP` this is why I asked..

Comment: Ah, alright. Thanks for clarifying!